# How to make listview snap to next position

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I'm trying to make a listview such that each item takes up the entire screen and when the user swipes up it should move to the next item. Im currently using a listview with a onscrollListner. The proble i have now is it is not very smooth. I was wondering if it would be possible to do something similar with listFragment?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [`VerticalViewPager`](https://github.com/LambergaR/VerticalViewPager/) widget created by Martin Sonc instead of `ListView`, as it is made for this usage.